# Computation of a likelihood for a discrete variable

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Let $U_1 \dots U_n $ be a i.i.d sample form an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. We only observe: $$Z_i = \mathbf{1}_{(U_i<c)}$$
>   Find the likelihood for $\lambda$.

I thought the following:

$$Z_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{if }\;  U_i < c  \\ 0 & \mbox{if }\; U_i \geq c  \end{cases}$$
implies that $P(Z_i=0)=P(U_i <c) $ and $P(Z_i=1)=P(U_i \geq c) $ and from this I can compute the likelihood. Since $Z_i$ can only take values $0$ or $1$, if $n_0$ is the number of times in which $z_i$ take value $0$ and $n_1=n-n_0$, I can write the likelihood for $\lambda $ as: 
$$L(Z,\lambda)= \prod^{n_1}_ {i=1}\left(1-e^{-\lambda c}\right)  \prod^{n_0}_ {i=1}\left(e^{-\lambda c}\right)$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: I guess a textbook/course that contains this exercise is eventually going to talk about 'censored' data. If a study has outcomes that may take a very long time to observe, one may stop at time $c$ and analyze the results that have occurred so far. Maybe you can read a little more on censoring now (in your text or online), while this example is fresh in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

As Did laconically remarked, the answer is "Yes."

Note that you can also write the product as

$$
L(Z,\lambda)=\left(\mathrm e^{-\lambda c}\right)^{n_0}\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda c}\right)^{n_1}\;.
$$